# Is there any way to teleport someone to the nether? (1.14)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanted to try to make a new dimension, by teleporting them over the bedrock in the nether.

> /execute as AaronKanaron in minecraft:the_nether run tp @p ~ 128 ~

I know I've done something wrong but I'm not the best at commands.

> /execute  in minecraft:the_nether run tp @p ~ 128 ~

Using this you get teleported to nether if you type it in chat, but is there a way to teleport someone to the nether by a command block?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "is there a way to teleport someone to the nether by a command block?", you litterally just put the first command in the command block and that's it.

Comment: That second command doesn't work for me, I get `Syntax error: Unexpected "minecraft:the_nether" at "xecute in >>minecraft:the_nether<< run tp ~"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh! I figured out the command!

> /execute as (player) run execute in minecraft:the_nether run tp (player) ~ 128 ~

Will teleport them over the bedrock in nether!

Comment: Both commands you had in the question worked for me though :o

Comment: You should replace the second (player) with @s. @s just means the player running the command, which is set by "as (player)". Also, don't forget to check mark your answer if you found the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Put /execute in `minecraft:the_nether run tp @p 0.0 128 0.0` in a command block. Once activated, the command block will teleport the nearest player to the roof.

If you want to teleport all players to the roof of the nether put `minecraft:the_nether run tp @a 0.0 128 0.0`

Comment: Thank! I guess there is no way to do tp ~ 128 ~?